# PHP Framework or No Framework for Matrimony like Website. Which one to Choose, if I use one?

Tags: php, frameworks

I read many times that Framework is not good for product development. Should I use one or it is just good for developing a software and shipping to client?

I read that YII is a fast framework, faster than other. Will it be good for me?

Please suggest with keeping in mind that I am looking for High traffic and high volume DB Website. Because I will only develop this as a pet project so it will also go several round of redesign to make it better.

I read at many places including stackoverflow that Framework is good in discussing things and it is easier for others to understand code. This advantage is not here as I will only develop this code.

I do not plan to market it as product but will use this myself in business if everything goes well.

Thanks!

Comment: If and what framework to use for a project is very subjective.

Comment: … and has dozens of duplicates (see the related column to the right).

Comment: Subjective questions are questions you get when you become smart! :)   
I have given example website here as well to understand the requirement well.

Comment: A decision can't be decided with no details on the project :)
Each case are spécificts and need reflexion.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash Please read the FAQ of this site. Subjective questions are not quite welcome here.

Answer (score 3):

Frameworks aid in agile development, especially when your goal is solely to produce something to market and test as soon as possible. Usually coming with MVC (albeit imperfect at times) patterns set-up, you can easily integrate code to your website without reorganization.

I would suggest looking into either of the following frameworks to get started:

**symfony**: http://www.symfony-project.org/

**Yii**: http://www.yiiframework.com/

**CakePHP**: http://cakephp.org/

**CodeIgnitor**: http://codeigniter.com/

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Just for MVC, should not I develop one for myself! Many here at stackoverflow suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. Personally I don't like using frameworks as I like knowing what each like is doing and that I can modify it. Using frameworks you usually get a fully functional component and you don't care, what's happening inside - you just care if it's working.

So here is the choice:

1. if you are short of time and want the project to be done quickly.  Use frameworks.
2. If you are going to work on the source code for a long time and you will need some unique and exceptional functionality. and if you are paranoid and you don't want to trust the security of somebody else written code. write yourself.

Or. If you are paid by the whole project as a piecework - use frameworks. If you are paid by hours, write yourself :)

Comment: No, it is a kind of pet project with me in it only. I may think of it as business if everything goes well.  :)
Performance is very important with scalability.